# How to remove the Wpf combo box item using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

i have 3 combo boxes with the same 3 items(a,b,c). If i select "a" in combobox1, "a" will remove from combobox2, items left in combobox2 will be "b" & "c". And then i select "b" in combobox2, "b" will remove from combobox3 and the item in combobox3 will be "a" & "c".
The removed item will restore back again into the combo box if the previous combobox going through the selectionChanged. I tried some codes i found on the internet, but doesnt work...the selected item from the previos combobox is not being removed.

My code for combo boxes:

```html
<ComboBox Name="firstCombo" SelectionChanged="firstCombo_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="secondCombo" SelectionChanged="secondCombo_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="thirdCombo" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

my C# code:

```cs
private void firstCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    secondCombo.Items.Remove(firstCombo.SelectionBoxItem);         
}

private void secondCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    thirdCombo.Items.Remove(secondCombo.SelectionBoxItem);         
}
```

Comment: What's the error? What if all items have been gradually removed from combobox? Anything to be left? And how do you continue your programme?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an error description. What is the problem?

Comment: sorry...i forgot to write out the error. I update the question already. Please have a look again. thanks.

Comment: To any prospective answerers - please note that OP has added the requirement that when the selection changes, unselected items are to be put back into the subsequent comboboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that those are actually different `ComboBoxItem` instances. They have the same text but they are still different instances. So, `SelectionBoxItem` from `secondCombo` will not be found in `thirdCombo.Items` and thus it won't be removed.

You need to remove it based on the displayed text.

Comment: so how could i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectedIndex to remove it but be aware of it if you have deleted something before or not because if you delete it already then the index isn't the same:

```
private void firstCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    secondCombo.Items.RemoveAt(firstCombo.SelectedIndex);         
}
```

Comment: That won't work. In the sample, after "A" has been removed from the second combo box, "B" will have index 0. This in turn will then remove "A" from the third combo box instead of "B".

Answer (score 0):

That to say, perhaps.

```
String strCombo1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
comboBox2.Items.Remove(strCombo1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding and removing items you could just change the visibility of the individual items.

If you bind it in the XAML (through a converter) the "removal" and "readding" would happen automatically.

```
<ComboBox Name="firstCombo">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="secondCombo">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A"
                  Visiblity="{Binding ElementName=firstCombo Path=SelectedIndex,
                              Converter=IndexToVisibiltyConverter,
                              ConverterParameter=A></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B"
                  Visiblity="{Binding ElementName=firstCombo Path=SelectedIndex,
                              Converter=IndexToVisibiltyConverter,
                              ConverterParameter=B></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"
                  Visiblity="{Binding ElementName=firstCombo Path=SelectedIndex,
                              Converter=IndexToVisibiltyConverter,
                              ConverterParameter=C></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="thirdCombo">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A"
                  Visiblity="{Binding ElementName=secondCombo Path=SelectedIndex,
                              Converter=IndexToVisibiltyConverter,
                              ConverterParameter=A></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B"
                  Visiblity="{Binding ElementName=secondCombo Path=SelectedIndex,
                              Converter=IndexToVisibiltyConverter,
                              ConverterParameter=B></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"
                  Visiblity="{Binding ElementName=secondCombo Path=SelectedIndex,
                              Converter=IndexToVisibiltyConverter,
                              ConverterParameter=C></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

*NOTE: Converter definition not legal syntax - illustrative only!

You could bind to the displayed text or selected value - whatever was most convenient.

The converter would check the index/text/value against the parameter and return `Visibility.Visible` or `Visibility.Collapsed` as appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply....i got 2 errors when i try to compile my file. Inner exception: When casting from a number, the value must be less than infinity. Inner exception: Make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type.

Comment: @0070 - I did say that the converter syntax was illustrative only!